# What should be the source impedance and load impedance in LC filter design?

Tags: mosfet, filter, passive-networks

My aim is to generate analog signals with class-D amplifier. For that I am using the following configuration:

Class-D-->Low-pass filter(LC)-->load(complex, real+imaginary)

class-D amplifies my PWM signal and then I feed that signal to a low-pass filter in order to remove all the high frequency components.

I am using a computer application for designing low-pass filter which asks for 3dB frequency, source impedance, load impedance, order of filter, filter type (Bessel, Butterworth). Everything is clear except source and load impedance. I want to drive a load which is \$78 - 220j\$. Output of class-D would be the input of LC filter. I am using MOSFET in H-bridge configuration to form class-D.

What should be the source impedance and load impedance in the design procedure?

Comment: It should be based on what source will be driving your filter and what load will be attached to its output.

Comment: LTSpice is free so try simulating it especially with the load impedance specified.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not able to understand what should be my source. Because i am using Mosfet to form class-D amplifier. Bus voltage is directly supplied from the voltage source to the drain of high-side mosfet. Source from high-side mosfet is connected directly to my filter. So in this case, what should be my source impedance?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to understand what should be my source

Your source will be a very low impedance - it is a class D amplifier with MOSFETs switching fairly hard to either power supply rail. It is likely that the MOSFET on-resistance will be sub 1 ohm and the power supply impedance sub 0.1 ohm so my estimation/guesstimation is around 1 ohm for your source impedance.

As for the load impedance I would definitely want to equip myself with a sim tool such as LTSpice for this.